# Really annoying WYSIWYG editor interaction with Vimperator

Tags: support, editor, firefox

I use [Vimperator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vimperator), a Firefox plugin which adds `vi` key bindings to my browser. I have problems with the WYSIWYG editor for the Trilogy sites. When I use `^I` in the textbox in gVim I get `*emphasized text*`. This is presumably because Vimperator and the WYSIWYG editor both want to bind on `^I`, and I assume that for a brief time the `*emphasized text*` is printed to the textbox buffer, which Vimperator picks up.

Is there any way I can stop the WYSIWYG editor from binding to any keystrokes, or prevent it from changing the contents of my textbox at all?

Comment: event that vimperator is the probem, just stop using vimperator and let the stackoverflow team get on with something of more value to the 99.9% of the users that don't need to do a 12 step VI admit program.

Comment: It should be possible to disable the use of this plugin for particular sites -- if not, that feature really needs to be added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We disable the WMD preview for smartphones, so you can, if you change your User-Agent to `iphone;` `ipad;` or `android n.n;`

Comment: So he will be faking an iphone with his Firefox that is faking `vim`?

Comment: @voyager this is Evan we're talking about... :)