# The /review page may be mishandling suspended users

Tags: bug, status-completed, account-suspension, review

I was just browsing through the ["first questions" tab of the MSO review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions), and saw this question on the list:

[Please retag MIME-type related tags on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58140/please-retag-mime-type-related-tags-on-stackoverflow)

However, there are much older questions posted by the same user on MSO; here's the oldest:

[Really annoying WYSIWYG editor interaction with Vimperator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33116/really-annoying-wysiwyg-editor-interaction-with-vimperator)

I suspect that the system is confused because the author of these questions is suspended, and therefore has a rep of 1 at the moment, which makes him look like a new user.

For what it's worth, I actually *like* the idea of suspended users' posts showing up more prominently on the `/review` page. Still reporting this as a bug in case it's tied to other issues, though.

Comment: I had to check for it... yes, RichB is in fact on that list if you move the timeline far enough back. Not for long, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, I think you are right.

The "first question" page is there for 2 reasons:

1. Give "great" new comer questions extra exposure, so they get more upvotes.
2. Give "poor" new comer questions extra exposure, so we help fix them up and bring them to shape.

The query selects all the first questions. Then it ads ALL the questions by users with 10 rep or less.

The problem with this approach is it is, incorrectly giving extra exposure to the good questions suspended users asked.

I went ahead and filtered out suspended users (we will now only show their first question)

Comment: to be deployed tonight

Comment: Here's another instance of this issue, with respect to Late Answers. I've seen this in the wild. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156042/dont-add-answers-from-suspended-users-in-the-late-answers-review-page