# Don't add answers from suspended users in the "Late Answers" review page

Tags: feature-request, review, account-suspension

Answers given from suspended users are added to the "Late Answers" review because are considered answers given from a new user simply for the fact the user's reputation is temporary reduced to 1.

[image: screenshot]

A user with an account from more than a year should not be considered a new user, especially when the user account's underlying reputation is more than 5,000.

Answers from suspended users should not be added to the "Late Answers" queue.
Adding in the review queue an answer that has been given in July 2011 for a question asked in May 2011 doesn't make sense, considering it is added to the review queue in November 2012. Probably the criteria about which answers are shown as late answers should be more restrictive.

Comment: I don't know... if a user has been suspended, I think I'd want more eyes on their posts just in case they do something else that is/was stupid.

Comment: That sounds like a different queue though

Comment: @jmort253 If the user has not been suspended for her/his own posts, I am not sure what the purpose of considering his posts as posts made from a new user would be.

Comment: Users who get suspended exhibit behaviors similar to new users: They just don't get the concept of what SE is about. The difference is that users who get suspended are more likely to go out of their way to break the rules, whereas noobs tend to simply be unaware of the rules. With that said, I'm not arguing against your feature request, as the late answers queue does indicate it's for new users, but what I'm wondering is if this is really a problem that needs to be fixed. What's the harm? Does the harm outweigh the possible benefit?

Comment: I guess one argument you might make is that, if the suspended user, prior to his or her suspension, tried to hijack something, it would be seen anyway, since edits and all posts get bumped up to the top. In short, I guess it doesn't really make sense to put these in the review queue. +1

Comment: @jmort253 Imagine a user who has an account since the site was created (about 1 year and a half ago), and who answered enough questions to reach a reputation between 5K, and 10K. If all in a sudden all his answers are put in the review queue because her/his reputation is temporary reduced to 1, then that is a little excessive. It is normally not possible to still be considered a new user after writing 280 answers. Even if the reputation doesn't change, an answer given more than 1 year ago is history. `:)`

Comment: @jmort253 `What's the harm?` I understand what you are saying, but I've had the same frustration as kiamlaluno, it doesn't just drop *an* answer of the suspended user, it's drops a bunch of them.  Perhaps up to 5 or a random sample would do, otherwise it's clogging the queue with a disproportionate number of posts from one user.

Comment: It's confusing when something shows up on the Late Answers queue that was posted a long time ago by a long-standing user.