# Disable Ctrl + B and other control characters in Stack Exchange editor?

Tags: feature-request, editor, mac

I use Firefox on a Mac to access Stack Exchange. I would like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to move the cursor to the left, as it does in other applications (an [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) key binding), but Stack Exchange's editor captures <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and makes text **bold** which is really not useful for me. (It also intercepts <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> **to make bold**.)

Is there a way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> and other control characters?

Comment: Are you talking about the old editor, [the new stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/348196) (that is still in beta and is only available for answers on MSO and MSE as well as on Teams), or both?

Comment: old, default editor.

Comment: There is no option to disable this using SE's stock code. You could write a userscript to get what you want. Probably the easiest way is to intercept the events for pressing that key combination and only permit the default action to be performed, rather than any event handlers which SE uses to perform the bolding. Note that you wouldn't want to prevent all such events for all such key combinations, as those events are used to trigger updating the preview. There are other possible ways to accomplish the same thing, which may be easier/harder/more elegant, but would require some investigation.

Comment: Related: *[Really annoying WYSIWYG editor interaction with Vimperator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33116/)*

Comment: One would expect this to have come up before. Has it? [A search on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=binding) does not seem to return anything significant. Are there some fundamental barriers? (Or not enough hardcore Unix users? :-))

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Being a Unix user doesn't necessitate you using Emacs, or even that you're familiar with the "normal" Emacs key bindings. There are plenty of other editors available in Unix/Linux. For example, I don't see SE shipping a version which is finger-feel compatible with vi/vim either. As users of a wide variety of software, we need to be adaptable, even if we have a preference. That doesn't mean SE shouldn't provide the ability to specify the key bindings, just that the *normal* thing is that we humans adapt to how we're giving input, or find a way to cause it to adapt to us.

Comment: One of the nice things at MacOS for EMACS users is that *every* text fields does the basic cursor-movement characters like ^a, ^b, ^e, ^f, ^k and so on.

Comment: [Also noted in 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/where-can-i-find-interesting-programming-discussions/13213#13213).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I guess this is the forum for common stack apps: https://stackapps.com/

Is there any way to migrate these topics over there?

Comment: This is not a stackapps.com issue, this is a StackExchange GUI issue. There is no obvious place to discuss such things.